# In tensorflow, why is the tf.equal(tf.size(x), 0) condition always False even for empty tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to first see whether a single tensor A is in another tensor B, and figure out the location of A in B, then use this location to extract a row in another tensor C. What I did: x=tf.where(tf.equal(A, B)), then extract_row = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.size(x), 0), if_true, if_false_v) where "if_true" is to set a default value if A is not in B and "if_false_v" is to extract row from C by x. However, I find the tf.equal(tf.size(x), 0) condition always False even when x is an empty tensor (A is not in B)... The weird thing is that when I run session to print tf.equal(tf.size(x), 0).eval(), the output is 'TRUE'...

Any solution for this issue? Thank you! Please find my codes below,

```
N = 100
k = 10
M = 2000

U = tf.constant(np.random.rand(N, k))
V = tf.constant(np.random.rand(M, k))
v_list = tf.constant(list(range(M)), tf.int64)
u_list = tf.constant(list(range(N)), tf.int64)

features = {‘c1’:tf.constant(234, tf.int64), ‘c2’:tf.constant(280, 
tf.int64)}

v_locate = tf.where(tf.equal(v_list, features[‘c1’]))

u_locate = tf.where(tf.equal(u_list, features[‘c2’]))

def if_true():
    return tf.constant(np.zeros((1, k)), tf.float64)
def if_false_u():
    return tf.reshape(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(U, u_locate), [1, k])
def if_false_v():
    return tf.reshape(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(V, v_locate), [1, k])
 
v_sel = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.size(v_locate), 0), if_true, if_false_v)   
u_sel = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.size(u_locate), 0), if_true, if_false_u)
```

Comment: tf.equal takes two tensors as inputs, I guess the issue lies in there.

That being said, your code seems to be wrong, e.g. `tf.size(x, 0)` doesn't work. You probably get better answers when you provide a minimal example where A,B,x are defined the way you define them in your code, and update your formulas so that they work with the variable definitions you provide.

Comment: sorry it's a typo in the title here. In my code, it's tf.equal(tf.size(x), 0)

Comment: When I run your code, `tf.equal(tf.size(u_locate), 0)` is `False` and `tf.equal(tf.size(u_locate), 0)` is `True`. What is the intended behavior? I can't quite relate your description to your example.